# Save audio file to a user-friendly location swift 3 avfoundation

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I am writing a simple recorder application which can record/play audio (via. AVFoundation) and save it locally to the iOS device. I've found several sources de

Initially, I would have liked to send out multiple of these saved audio files via email (MessageUI) such as with this simple example: https://gist.github.com/kellyegan/49e3e11fe68b5e6b5360 - though recently I have felt maybe I should forego this in favor of simply saving to the device and allowing the user to send out the file somehow.

Considering this, I feel it might be best to try to save the audio file to a more user-friendly destination. Is there any way I can save these files locally that might allow the user to 'share' them via iOS (outside of my application)? Maybe even to their iTunes library? This seemed promising: [iOS - Save audio files to iTunes music library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28711577/ios-save-audio-files-to-itunes-music-library) - but looks like the solution provided is actually for saving images to the 'photo album'

When I print the audio file's URL I get something like

```
'file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AA3E5177-A8C8-4FFA-8EBC-85A2A6844A88/Documents/recording-2017-03-06-12-54.m4a'
```

I am a serious noob w/ Swift 3 and definitely with AVFoundation - I'd really appreciate any and all help/advice. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The URL `'file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AA3E5177-A8C8-4FFA-8EBC-85A2A6844A88/Documents/recording-2017-03-06-12-54.m4a'` may look elaborate to you, but in fact it is *totally* "user-friendly". It's a file in the app's Documents folder! Nothing could be simpler than that.

The URL in question would never be seen by the user; in fact, it won't even be the same between runs of your app.

Your app can certainly provide interface for the user to select one or more files, and can make them available for sharing out by means of UIActivityViewController or UIDocumentInteractionController.

You might also want to look into UIDocumentPickerViewController or even https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/FileProvider.html

Answer (score 2):

iOS apps are heavily sandboxed. The app's Documents directory (at the path you posted) is the typical place for files like this. You can enable file sharing from the app in iTunes (on the user's computer) by adding the `UIFileSharingEnabled` key (Application supports iTunes file sharing) to your `Info.plist` file.

The typical way to enable sharing within the app is by using `UIDocumentInteractionController` or `UIActivityViewController`.